# Restart All Bundles In OSGi

Tags: osgi, aem

I am looking over the command to either restart or refresh the OSGi container such as Apache Felix through command line like curl.

This command I use to start single bundle, is there similar which restart all bundles.

```
curl -u admin:admin -F action=start http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles/$bundle symbolic name
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with:

```
curl -u admin:admin -d "shutdown_type=Restart" http://localhost:4502/system/console/vmstat
```

**[Reference](https://github.com/paulrohrbeck/aem-links/blob/master/curl_cheatsheet.md)**